# How AppDynamics 4.4 to track async transaction

Tags: asynchronous, appdynamics

Consider below code:

```
public class Job {
    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public void process() {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            // do something slow
        }
    }
}
```

I could use AppDynamics "Java POJO" rule to create a business transaction to track all the calls to Job.process() method. But the measured response time didn't reflect real cost by the async thread started by java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService. This exact problem is also described in AppDynamics document: [End-to-End Latency Performance](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO44/End-to-End+Latency+Performance) that:

> The return of control stops the clock on the transaction in terms of measuring response time, but meanwhile the logical processing for the transaction continues.

The same AppDynamics document tries to give a solution to address this issue but the instructions it provides is not very clear to me.

Could anyone give more executable guide on how to configure AppD to track async calls like the one shown above?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you schould be able to define your custom **Asynchronous Transaction Demarcator** as described in:
 https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO44/Asynchronous+Transaction+Demarcators

which will point to the last method of Runnable that you passes to the Executor. Then according to the documentation all you need is to attach the Demarcator to your Business Transaction and it will collect the asynchronous call.